# Dynamic SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I Have created a procedure which is:

CREATE PROCEDURE test.table_creation ( @ID INT )
AS 
    BEGIN

```
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)

    SELECT  @SQL = 'Create Table ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + '('
    SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 'ID int NOT NULL Primary Key, Name VarChar(10))'

    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

The problem here is I have to get the table name and Schema name from another table called sample. The query to get those is:

SELECT Source_Schema,Source_Table FROM sample where ID = 12

How do i use these values in the above procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a dubious requirement (you might want to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)) but

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test.table_creation (@ID INT)
AS
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000) /*Use nvarchar*/
      DECLARE @SchemaName sysname /*Use sysname*/
      DECLARE @TableName sysname

      SELECT @SchemaName = Source_Schema,
             @TableName = Source_Table
      FROM   sample
      where  ID = @ID


       /*Use QUOTENAME*/
      SELECT @SQL = 'Create Table ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' +
                    QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
                           '(ID int NOT NULL Primary Key, Name VarChar(10))'

      EXEC (@SQL)
  END
```

Comment: @Martin What is the use of using Sysname and Quotename instead of varchar

Comment: The thought of someone creating tables on the fly through a proc fills me with dread! But if you must do it, you might also want to add a check for the existance of the table before you create it this way.

Comment: @HLGEM - If the table already exists then it will throw an error so I'm not sure what would be gained by checking first then using `raiserror`? @Sam - `QUOTENAME` deals correctly with escaping problematic characters in object names. `sysname` and unicode as object names can be unicode. Also I just use that as a precaution when dealing with dynamic SQL to prevent innocuous characters such as `ʼ` being coverted to problematic characters such as `'`

Comment: @Martin I tried to create the procedure as per your suggestions but I get a error saying : Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 77 Incorrect syntax near ','.   I Have Total 92 columns in my Create Table Staetment When I reduce the columns it runs fine. Can you tell me how do I include all the 92 columns in my Procedure. I have Increased the size of variable SQL to nvarchar(max)

Comment: @Sam I would like to second the note to read the link about dynamic sql. It is long but well worth it to keep from causing yourself other problems.

Comment: @Sam - changing the datatype to `nvarchar(max)` should be all you need to do. To see what the variable contains without SSMS truncating it (as might happen with `print`) you can use `SELECT @SQL as [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
   @SchemaName = Source_Schema, 
   @TableName = Source_Table
FROM sample where ID = 12
```

Comment: Where do I put the Code in my Procedure